# Appium iOS real device - is it possible to use chrome for web testing?

Tags: appium, appium-ios

After trying simulators from xCode and Android Studios for a while, I finally moved on to get real iOS and Android devices to run with appium.
But the issue I'm facing is that I cannot use chrome as a browser on iOS devices (iPhone 5) to run my web based application which I'm trying to test. 
I used `Chrome` as `browser` and `com.google.chrome.ios` as `bundleId` in my desired capabilities. 
eg:

```
{   
   platformName: 'iOS',
   platformVersion: '10.3',
   browserName:'Chrome',
   deviceName: 'my iPhone 5',
   uuid: "<uuid>",
   xcodeOrgId: '<Team ID>',
   xcodeSigningId: 'iPhone Developer',
   bundleId: 'com.google.chrome.ios'
}
```

I did a fair amount of research to find any information regarding this issue but no success. 
I'd appreciate it if anyone knows of any articles or an answer to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to use any browser other than Safari with iOS yet.

Comment: Have you ran across Safari acting weird with tests? I use jasmine/protractor for my tests. The same test that runs perfectly on Android devices with google chrome fails on iOS devices with safari. It seems to click on random elements on a page and not the one that I have defined.

Comment: Knows Safari driver issues, but we are stuck with it for iOS and can't use Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, only Safari + iOS is possible. Review [this](https://discuss.appium.io/t/is-there-any-way-to-launch-chrome-browser-in-ios/22759/5), [5569](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/5569).